# How to do Chromatic Aberration on a transparent background?

Tags: c#, xna, shaders, hlsl, monogame

I have a problem with a chromatic aberration shader effect...

If I produce the effect on a white background I get exactly what I want:

[image]

But if I do the same effect on a transparent background I get this:

[image]

In my code I use the following shader to produce the chromatic aberration effect:

```
// Chromatic Aberration

float DisplacementX = 5;
float DisplacementY = 5;

sampler TextureSampler : register(s0);

float4 main(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR0, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{

// Offset the main texture coordinates.
float2 texCoord2 = float2(texCoord.x + DisplacementX, texCoord.y + DisplacementY);

float2 texCoord3 = float2(texCoord.x - DisplacementX, texCoord.y - DisplacementY);

float4 color1 = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord);
float4 color2 = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord2);
float4 color3 = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord3);

float alpha = color1.a + color2.a + color3.a;

// Look up into the main texture.
return float4 (color1.r, color2.g, color3.b, alpha);

}

technique RGBSplit
{

pass Pass0
{

PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 main();

}
}
```

This works great when I set the whole screen to a render target and apply the effect but I want to be able to apply this effect only to the foreground so I can choose which sprites it effects and then draw the background behind the transparent space.

My thinking so far is that I could create a white layer of the foreground image and blend it with the chromatic layer to produce the correct effect like this:

```
return float4(1, 1, 1, alpha); // Produces white version of layer
```

But I've unsuccessfully managed to blend it and I always end up with the same result as the second image.

I know this is possible because Teleglitch uses the same effect on bullets etc without effecting the background.

[image]

Perhaps someone with better blending knowledge than myself can help point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to add the alpha channels together. It might be more sensible would be to use the max of the 3.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution for this, if anyone else can think of a better way please let me know.

If I set the backbuffer of the foreground layer to white with an opacity of 99% or something like that:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White * 0.99f);
```

The shader will blend the foreground with the white creating the chromatic aberration like I want.

Then I pass over the final texture and remove any pixels that have transparency (which is the white background). So the new shader looks like this:

```
// Chromatic Aberration

float DisplacementX = 5;
float DisplacementY = 5;

sampler TextureSampler : register(s0);

float4 main(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR0, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{

// Offset the main texture coordinates.
float2 texCoord2 = float2(texCoord.x + DisplacementX, texCoord.y + DisplacementY);

float2 texCoord3 = float2(texCoord.x - DisplacementX, texCoord.y - DisplacementY);

float4 color1 = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord);
float4 color2 = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord2);
float4 color3 = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord3);

float alpha = color1.a * color2.a * color3.a;

float4 finalTex = float4(color1.r, color2.g, color3.b, alpha);
if (finalTex.a <= 0.975f)
{
    clip(-1); // Abandon Pixel with transparency
}

// Look up into the main texture.
return finalTex;

}

technique RGBSplit
{

pass Pass0
{

PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 main();

}
}
```

The result means I can perform chromatic aberration on individual sprites then overlay them onto a background that doesn't use the effect.

Comment: Please visit this page to get your accounts merged: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts